# How to retrieve my shipments from FedEx using order number or reference number or invoice number

Tags: c#, asp.net, fedex

I am stuck with FedEx API Integration in an ASP.NET website, as I cannot find proper documentation about their API on their website.

What I am trying to do is: our client has a tool that will create shipment using the FedEx API.

Now we need to show the tracking detail on our website (which is diff from the client's software). To do so, I need to update the track number of that shipment in my database.

How can I get the shipment detail along with tracking number from FedEx using the *ORDER NUMBER* or *REFERENCE NUMBER* or *INVOICE NUMBER* ?

Comment: were you able to do it ?

Comment: @Ronak Patel is it possible, do you remember the solution?

Answer (score -1):

`POST` a request like:

> https://www.fedex.com/trackingCal/track?action=trackpackages&location=en_US&version=1&format=json&data={"TrackPackagesRequest":{"appType":"WTRK","uniqueKey":"","processingParameters":{},"trackingInfoList":[{"trackNumberInfo":{"trackingNumber":"TRCKING_NUMBER","trackingQualifier":"","trackingCarrier":""}}]}}

replace `TRACKING_NUMBER`.
I have queried only `tracking number`, you should do minor change to fix it with other NUMBER.

Comment: you are not getting my question. I do not have tracking number and i do not need tracking status. I need the shipment detail including tracking number. I have just the order number or invoice number